# affectiva affdex issue with detecting emotions from a photo

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, imagemagick, embedded-linux, affdex-sdk

i’m trying to analyse an image with affdex SDK (like the seconde example done by Abdelrahman Mahmoud [link for tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tSx3xlWNnc&list=PL4uhb2yWZJbxnoqeLQ5O_EsKMUiGYy5zt&index=3) ) i’m using raspberry pi 3b running Raspbian stretch with gcc 6.3.0

the code :

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Magick++.h"
#include "PhotoDetector.h"

class Listener : public affdex::ImageListener{
 void onImageResults(std::map<affdex::FaceId,affdex::Face> faces,affdex::Frame image){
  std::cout << "Found Faces: "<< faces.size() << std::endl;

  for (auto pair : faces){
   std::string pronoun="they";
   std::string emotion="neutral";
   affdex::Face face=pair.second;

   if(face.appearance.gender == affdex::Gender::Male){
    pronoun="He";
   }
   else if(face.appearance.gender == affdex::Gender::Female){
    pronoun="She";
   }
   if(face.emotions.joy>25){
    emotion="Happy :)";
   }
   else if(face.emotions.sadness>25){
    emotion="Sad :(";
   }
   
   std::cout << face.id << " : " << pronoun << " looks " << emotion << std::endl;
  }
 };
 
 void onImageCapture(affdex::Frame image){};
};

int main(int argc, char ** argsv)
{
 
 //Initialize the imagemagick library
 Magick::InitializeMagick(*argsv);
 
 // Read Image into Memory
 Magick::Image img(argsv[1]);
 char * pixels = new char [img.columns() * img.rows() * 1];
 img.write(0,0,img.columns(), img.rows(), "RGB", MagickCore::StorageType::CharPixel, pixels);
 
 affdex::Frame frame(img.columns(), img.rows(), pixels, affdex::Frame::COLOR_FORMAT::BGR);
 
 affdex::PhotoDetector detector(1);
 affdex::ImageListener * listen = new Listener();
 
 detector.setImageListener(listen);
 
 detector.setClassifierPath("/home/pi/affdex-sdk/data");
 detector.setDetectAllEmotions(true);
 detector.setDetectAllAppearances(true);
 detector.setDetectAllExpressions(true);
 
 detector.start();
 detector.process(frame);
 detector.stop();

 delete listen;
 delete [] pixels;
 return 0;
}
```

when i run the script with

> ./test-app image.jpg

i got this error (the same if i use .bmp image ):

> segmentation fault

i tried with an other image and i got this error :

> terminate called after throwing an instance of ‘Magick::ErrorResourceLimit’ ** what(): test-app: memory allocation failed `download.png’ @ error/png.c/ReadOnePNGImage/2341 
>   Aborted

Any pointers, thanks

Comment: from the symptoms described, it sounds like the error is coming from ImageMagick, not the Affex SDK.  Can you debug into the ImageMagick code and determine why it's throwing that exception?

Comment: yes , i found this error :
what(): basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

Comment: that's just the exception message.  Why is it throwing the exception?  ImageMagick is open source, you should be able to debug into it and see why it's throwing.

Comment: also, you may get more assistance if you change the title and tag of your question to reference ImageMagick, as the problem  you're encountering doesn't seem to have anything to do with the Affectiva SDK.

Comment: thank you for your response sir , sorry i'm a beginner  i don't know how to debug into the ImageMagick code can you help me

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, however, I think you may get more assistance for this issue if you change the title of the question to something like "Magick::ErrorResourceLimit error from ImageMagick library" and reduce your code example to just the couple of lines that are relevant:

 //Initialize the imagemagick library
 Magick::InitializeMagick(*argsv);
 
 // Read Image into Memory
 Magick::Image img(argsv[1]);
 char * pixels = new char [img.columns() * img.rows() * 1];
 img.write(0,0,img.columns(), img.rows(), "RGB", MagickCore::StorageType::CharPixel, pixels);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pixels` buffer isn't large enough to accept all the data.

```cpp
size_t pixels_size = img.columns() // Width
                   * img.rows()    // Height
                   * sizeof(char)  // Size of storage
                   * 3;            // Number of parts per pixel ("RGB")
char * pixels = new char [pixels_size];
img.write(0,0,img.columns(), img.rows(), "RGB", MagickCore::StorageType::CharPixel, pixels);
```